# Matching urls in html link elements using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract URLs that are within  and match both tags that have a close  as well as open/unclosed  that have hrefs in them.

That said here is the regex:

```
<(\w+)\s[^<>]*?href=[\'"]([\w$-_.+!*\'\(\),%\/:#=?~\[\]!&@;]*?)[\'"].*?>((.+?)</\1>)?
```

Here is some sample data:

```
<link href='http://blah.net/message/new/?stopemails.aspx?id=5A42FDF5' /><table><tr><td>
<a href='http://blah.net/message/new/'>Click here and submit your updated information </a> <br><br>Thanking you in advance for your attention to this matter.<br><br>

Regards, <br>
Debbi Hamilton
</td></tr><tr><td><br><br></td></tr></table>
```

And putting this in http://re-try.appspot.com/ or http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html (yes I know it's for java) yields precisely what I am trying to get: the tag, the href text, the enclosed text with the end tag, and the enclosed text by itself.

That said, when I use this in my python app, the last two groups (enclosed text w/ tag, and enclosed text by itself) are always `None`. I suspect it has something to do with the group within a group with a back reference: ((.+?))?

```
Also, I should mention that I specifically use:
    matcher = re.compile(...)
    matcher.findall(data)
```

but the groups being `None` appears in both `matcher.search(data)` and `matcher.match(data)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respectfully, what you want to do is very silly, and you shouldn't do it.

That said, it seems to work for me (by which I mean gives non-None results):

```
>>> reg = r'<(\w+)\s[^<>]*?href=[\'"]([\w$-_.+!*\'\(\),%\/:#=?~\[\]!&@;]*?)[\'"].*?>((.+?)</\1>)?'
... 
>>> d = """
<link href='http://blah.net/message/new/?stopemails.aspx?id=5A42FDF5' /><table><tr><td>
<a href='http://blah.net/message/new/'>Click here and submit your updated information </a> <br><br>Thanking you in advance for your attention to this matter.<br><br>
Regards, <br>
Debbi Hamilton
</td></tr><tr><td><br><br></td></tr></table>
"""
>>> 
>>> re.findall(reg, d)
[('link', 'http://blah.net/message/new/?stopemails.aspx?id=5A42FDF5', '', ''), 
('a', 'http://blah.net/message/new/', 'Click here and submit your updated information </a>', 'Click here and submit your updated information ')]
```

My guess is that you forgot to use a raw string when making the regular expression, i.e.

```
>>> reg = '<(\w+)\s[^<>]*?href=[\'"]([\w$-_.+!*\'\(\),%\/:#=?~\[\]!&@;]*?)[\'"].*?>((.+?)</\1>)?'
... 
>>> re.findall(reg, d)
[('link', 'http://blah.net/message/new/?stopemails.aspx?id=5A42FDF5', '', ''), 
('a', 'http://blah.net/message/new/', '', '')]
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I forgot about that. I realize trying to parse HTML via regex is horrible, that said, what I'm using this for is more of proof of concept with extracting some URLs within tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
pat = ('<'
       '(\w+)\s[^<>]*?'
       'href='
       '([\'"])'
       '([\w$-_.+!*\'(\),%/:#=?~[\]!&@;]*?)'
       '(?:\\2)'
       '.*?'
       '>'
       '((.+?)</\\1>)?')
```

You just needed to put `\\1` or `r'...'` as did DSM

Note that I made minor modifications in your pattern:
there were two `!`
writing `[\]` instead of `\[\]` because it's clear for the regex machinery that `[` after a first `[` is a simple character
the same for `(\)`

Note that I did a group of `([\'"])` and put `(?:\\2)` to catch the same at the end